Automatically scrolling to first row in attribute table after selecting features on map in QGIS
Is there an option to automatically scroll to the first row in the attribute table, when selecting features on the map?
I'm working on QGIS version 3.40.0-Bratislava.
When I'm working with data on the map and selecting features (e.g., dragging an area with the mouse cursor). With the attribute table open, I'd like to have the attribute table automatically scroll down/up the first selected feature.

There is the "Move selection to top" button (the one with the blue up arrow).
When activated, the selected feature will automatically move to the top of the attribute table. This has the advantage of letting you see other non-selected features at the same time.


To view only selected features in the attribute table, select "Show Selected Feature" in the drop-down.

